# How to get conditional average data for graph in mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregate

Data 1:

```
{
    "_id" : "5eb922b4c019811689c8f8e3",
    "createdAt" : "2020-05-10T19:30:00.000Z",
    "isManual" : false,
    "value" : 0.66
}
```

Data 2:

```
{
    "_id" : "5eb922b4c019811689c8f8e3",
    "createdAt" : "2020-05-10T19:30:00.000Z",
    "isManual" : false,
    "value" : 0.52
}
```

Data 3:

```
    {
        "_id" : "5eb922b4c019811689c8f8e3",
        "createdAt" : "2020-05-10T19:30:00.000Z",
        "isManual" : true,
        "value" : 0.34
    }
```

Now I need to generate a query for getting an average of **value** field. Consider **isManual**
key for average:

```
Response key expected:
total_fields = 3
manual_avg = 0.34 ((0.66 + 0.52)/3)
not_manual_avg = 0.13 ((0.34)/3)
```

Comment: Have you attempted to find an answer? If so please include what you have tried.

Comment: Also (0.66 + 0.52)/3 = 0.39, not 0.34

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try below aggregation query :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    /** group all docs in collection */
    {
      $group: {
        _id: null,
        total_fields: { $sum: 1 }, /** count total no.of docs */
        manual_avg: { $avg: { $cond: [ "$isManual", 0, "$value" ] } }, /** If 'isManual' is true pass-in 0 else actual value to average */
        not_manual_avg: { $avg: { $cond: [ "$isManual", "$value", 0 ] } }
      }
    },
    /** Optional stage */
    {
      $project: { _id: 0,total_fields: 1, manual_avg: { $trunc: [ "$manual_avg", 2 ] }, not_manual_avg: { $trunc: [ "$not_manual_avg", 2 ] }
      }
    }
  ])
```

**Test :** [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/fgxBIKvhqbZ)

Comment: 1. In the mongoplayground link, the not_manual_avg field in the result gives the avg for documents where `isManual` is true and vice versa.
2. If you look at the average values, the 0 being supplied in the `$cond` will be factored into the avg calculation and will not give accurate average of values where the `isManual` boolean is/isn't set.

Comment: @AnujPancholi (1) That's exactly what OP wants, check the question - if not it's just a minor variable name change but major concept is answered. (2) I don't think you've got what's happening there!! Please debug line to line, adding 0 doesn't change anything here (0.66 + 0.52 + 0)/3 = 0.39 or (0.66 + 0.52)/3 = 0.39, both are the same..!! Any doc's with `isManual !== Boolean` or missing have to be filtered at first step or needs a pre-check. If you still are confused, raise a new question & ping here or someone will pick to solve it :-)

Comment: Ohk... oops! I understand it's what OP asked for, but, come to think about it, regarding point no.2 in my last comment - shouldn't the avg value of the docs where `isManual`===`false` be *only* the avg of those docs where `isManual: false` ((0.66+0.52)/2)? Actually this is my usecase (which led me to this ques), OP's use case seems to be different. Any ideas as to how I can to this? I could post a ques but I'd probably get flagged as duplicate.

Comment: @AnujPancholi: You need to understand your requirements are whole diff than OP's!! Yours should be simple as well,Sum all the values using condition, at the same time count no.of docs matching the given condition & in the end divide (sum of values/count), try this : https://mongoplayground.net/p/dwCEfBNCqPh

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) along with [`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) to count for `total_field` and to do the sum based on `isManual` condition using [`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/)

```
[
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      count: {
        $sum: 1
      },
      manual: {
        $sum: {
          $cond: [
            "$isManual",
            "$value", // add $value when $isManual is true
            0
          ]
        }
      },
      not_manual: {
        $sum: {
          $cond: [
            "$isManual",
            0,
            "$value" // add $value when $isManual is false
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: false,
      total_fields: "$count",
      manual_avg: {
        $divide: [
          "$manual",
          "$count"
        ]
      },
      not_manual_avg: {
        $divide: [
          "$not_manual",
          "$count"
        ]
      } 
    }
  }
]
```